# Using an EMF Resource without persisting it

Tags: model, resources, persistence, eclipse-emf

I have a Resource, which has been created after a programmatic model-to-model transformation with QVT and it holds the output of the transformed model. For now it is being persisted into an xmi-file. But I want to give this transformed model to another method as a parameter for further use (search etc.), without persisting it.

How should I realize it? I believe, it is not easy -or maybe even not possible- to use a Resource without persisting it. Don't I have to create also a specific URI for this Resource? And doesn't it mean persisting it?

Should I then use the model elements directly, as they are still a List of EObjects? If so, I will have to make some changes to my whole project, since this other method, which needs the model output(that is for now being persisted), uses a Resource object.

Would be very thankful for any kind of help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For every ResourceURI you have to save the file into xmi.I think it is mandatory to save this every time.If you want to give this transformed model to another method then whenever you will try to access this Resource this will create an eProxy() and will give the reference of that.
So that would be difficult to access.So if you want to pass the reference then save it in xmi then pick it

ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

```
// Get the resource
Resource resource = resSet.getResource(URI
    .createURI("test"), true);
```